# Having a git repo remote that maps different folders

Tags: git

I have a local git with the following structure

- myapp/application_files
- myapp/public

Is it possible to map the remote git so that the application files go to the root directory and public goes to /public_html?

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, so answering this question as written is impossible.  What is your desire, that `git push` to the server would automatically publish?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to deploy using Git. Git is not a deployment tool, it's a version control system. You need a different tool for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes.  Using push would map to different folders on the server.  I'm trying to use it to simplify my test server.

Comment: If you're using git as a deployment tool, which _is_ possible, you could probably use git hooks for that. I haven't used them yet, but at least I can tell you what to google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The way that source control is meant to be used is to keep all members of the team on the same track, and not have each have their own customized view of the files within source control. Like others have said, it is likely that you are wanting to have a build system such as Microsoft Build or Atlassian Bamboo to help with doing the builds and publish.